# how to fill gridview column first in android

Tags: android, gridview

In my application I have a GridView containing some items.
I want to fill GridView columns first with those element.
By default, 2x3 GridView orders my items in this way:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Nh9a.png

What i want is that would fill whole column first:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1XnX.png

For now, my solution is in my adapters getView() method create and return invisible View for empty blocks. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can think it as matrix. Therefore, you can fill the ArrayList however you want to fill inside a loop.The ArrayList which you gave as a parameter for the grid's adapter.

Comment: Super solution.! ratherthan doing it on a getview method. just sort the arraylist and give it adapter.